# How to override doubletap of PhotoView

Tags: android, double, tap, photoviewer

I want to set scale=4 after doubletap

in onCreate():

```
         imageView = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
         mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(imageView);
         imageLoader.displayImage(globalWallImages.get(position).preview, imageView, options);
         mAttacher.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
```

I'm setting `mAttacher.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);`
and in method of this interface doing it:

```
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.e("","onDoubleTap");
        mAttacher.setScale(4);
        return true;
    }
```

but image don't want to scale

Comment: Did you set a scaleType via XML on the ImageView? This could change behavior of setScale method I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found solution

by defauld MaximumScale is < 4, so I add:

```
mAttacher.setMaximumScale(5f);
```